# overwrite content of textarea java

Tags: java

I am appending text to text area for every sec I wanted to overwrite or clear the old text and i want write new data for every one sec. How to do this in Java?

Comment: What is your code doing?  setText should remove the current text and enter whatever you specify as the new text.  Is it possible that the parameter you are passing to setText actually contains the previous text with the new text appended to it?  Can you show us a snippet of your code?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are talking about a Swing `JTextArea`.

You can just call `setText(...)` on it to replace the text:

```
JTextArea textArea = ...;

textArea.setText("Hello World");
```

Comment: Are you sure it is appending? Do some debugging: Check what you are passing to setText(). Is it the new text only, or are you setting it to old text + new text?

Comment: Note that you can mark an answer as the accepted solution on StackOverflow, if you think it's the right answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

To do something periodically you need some thread, but be aware to use [SwingWorker](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). If not your GUI may freeze.

```
        final JTextArea ta = frame.getjTextArea1();

        SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                while (true) {
                   ta.setText("");
                   ta.setText(new Date().toString());
                   Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        };
        worker.execute();
```